# Give role to user in message

Tags: python, discord

```
print("dsdsdd")
import discord
import time
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

TOKEN = "..."
ROLE = "Rekrutant"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "/")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Zalogowano: " + bot.user.name)

@bot.command()
async def setup(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
        ADMIN_ROLE = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Admin")
        if (ADMIN_ROLE in ctx.author.roles):
            await user.add_roles("Rozmowy+")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Nie masz uprawnien, aby uzywac komendy")

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

I have problem with getting user form message.

I got an error:
await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'

I don't know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are putting a string into the add_roles function, which really wants a role object instead. Try:

```
await ctx.author.add_roles(discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles,name="Rozmowy+"))
```

This new function turns the string into a role object, which is what the original function was looking for. Also, I changed user to ctx.author, because that was the only user object that worked for me. If you need any clarification, ask me in a comment down below.